# Implicit differentiation

Tags: implicit-differentiation

Question: Find the gradient of the curve $x \ln y - \frac{x}{y}=2$ at $(-1,1)$

I've done something wrong as I got the gradient to be $0$ when the answer in the back says $-0.5$

Can someone help me with this question?

edit:

I got:
$1+\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y-x\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2}$

$y^2+y\frac{dy}{dx}-y-x\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y-y^2}{y-x}$

Substituting the values in did not get me the answer

Comment: It would be better to include your work in the post.

Comment: I've edited my working in :)

Answer (score 1):

When you differentiate you get:
$$
\ln{y}+\frac{x}{y}y'-\frac{y-xy'}{y^2}=0
$$

Then substituting $x=-1,y=1$ you obtain: $-y'-(1+y')=0$ so $y'=-1/2$.